# VS Code : How to fold C# xml comments?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, comments

I liked how Visual Studio 2017 had the ability to collapse XML documentation inside C# files:

[[image: VS2017 Comment folding]

---

However, I can't seem to get that capability in Visual Studio Code 1.9:

[image: No folding]

---

Is there a way to collapse XML comments in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: This is a known issue and heavily cited here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/105

Comment: I'm currently only on an extension to solve this particular issue

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collapse at any certain point, just highlight and select the code you want to collapse, and use following keys to fold & unfold.

Shortcut Keys:

**Fold** (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`[` on Windows, `⌥`+`⌘`+`[` on OS X) folds the innermost uncollapsed region at the cursor

**Unfold** (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`]` on Windows, `⌥`+`⌘`+`]` on OS X) unfolds the collapsed region at the cursor

**Fold All** (`Ctrl`+`K` `Ctrl`+`0` `(zero)` on Windows, `⌘`+`K` `⌘`+`0` `(zero)` on OS X) folds all region in the editor

**Unfold All** (`Ctrl`+`K` `Ctrl`+`J` on Windows, `⌘`+`K` `⌘`+`J` on OS X) unfolds all regions in the editor

These are VS-Code Defaults.

Thank You , I Hope This Might Help.

Comment: Yes . Because right now i dont find any extension regarding comments folding and unfloding as Visual Studio has some. until then this method works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found you can indent the comments in a manner similar to code.

```
/*
  Start (providing a visual reference, regions are not required)
     This is
     the collapsible
     region of comment
  */
```

For reference, the below will not create a collapsible comment.

```
/*
     This is
     the collapsible
     region of comment
  */
```